# Error on DECLARE variable in MySql procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, database, stored-procedures

I'm trying to create a simple stored procedure like this:

```
CREATE DEFINER = 'root'@'localhost'
PROCEDURE testProcedure()
BEGIN

  DECLARE variableAaa INT;
  DECLARE variableBbb INT;

END
```

but I get this error from MySql:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'END' at line 1

If I change the variable names:

```
DECLARE variableA INT;
DECLARE variableB INT;
```

I get error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'DECLARE variableB INT' at line 1

and so on:

```
DECLARE variableName INT;
DECLARE variableEmail INT;
```

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'DECLARE variableEmail INT' at line 1

I'm using MySql 5.5.34 with PhpMyAdmin, but it's the same with Sequel Pro.

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like its an issue of delimiter which you are missing

So the procedure should look like

```
delimiter //
CREATE DEFINER = 'root'@'localhost'
PROCEDURE testProcedure()
BEGIN

  DECLARE variableAaa INT;
  DECLARE variableBbb INT;

END ; //

delimiter ;
```

Here I tried the same on MySql and it works

```
mysql> delimiter //
mysql> create procedure testProcedure()
    -> begin
    -> DECLARE variableAaa INT;
    -> DECLARE variableBbb INT;
    -> end; //
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> delimiter ;
```

Comment: When using phpMyAdmin, I had to begin my code with a delimiter, i.e. `;` right before specifying a different delimiter (i.e. `//`, in this case).

Comment: `;` will be treated as inidividual mysql statements, so to enclose the procedure and statements consist of `;` you will need to define a delimiter before the procedure and trigger so that everything inside the delimiter is processed without any confusion.