# mysql error while declaring variable

Tags: mysql

It s a huge query..While executing the following procedure, it shows that

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use 
>   near 'DECLARE i integer' at line 2.

What is the mistake in my query.

```
DELIMITER $$
BEGIN
DECLARE i integer $$
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_tags;     
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_tags (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`org_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`tag_id` varchar(150) NOT NULL,PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    );
  SET i = 1;
  REPEAT
  INSERT INTO tmp_tags ( org_id, user_id, tag_id)
      SELECT org_id,user_id ,strSplit(tag_id, ',', i) FROM tagging
      WHERE strSplit(tag_id, ',', i) IS NOT NULL;
    SET i = i + 1;
    UNTIL ROW_COUNT() = 0
  END REPEAT;
  DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_tagged_org;
    IF userId IS NULL THEN      
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_tagged_org AS
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( organization_tag.tag_name
SEPARATOR ', ' ) AS tags,tmp_tags.org_id AS tagged_org_id
FROM organization_tag
INNER JOIN tmp_tags ON organization_tag.id = tmp_tags.tag_id
GROUP BY tmp_tags.org_id;
SELECT calllist.id AS DT_RowId,tagging.tag_id, tmp_tagged_org.tags AS display_tag, organization.name, (

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( CONCAT( CONCAT( contacts.first_name, ' ', contacts.last_name ), ':', contacts.phone )
SEPARATOR '<br> ' )
FROM contacts
WHERE organization.id = org_id
) AS
unames, CONCAT(calllist.call_back_date,' ' , if(calllist.call_back_date < now(), '<label style='position:absolute;'><i class='fa fa-warning' style='color:red'></i></label> ', '')) as calldate, IF(tmp_tagged_org.tags IS NULL,'<input type='hidden' class='servicetags' style=' width:150px'>',CONCAT('<input type='hidden' class='servicetags' value='',tmp_tagged_org.tags,'' style=' width:150px' >')) as tag_name
FROM calllist
INNER JOIN organization ON organization.id = calllist.org_id
LEFT JOIN tmp_tagged_org ON tmp_tagged_org.tagged_org_id =  calllist.org_id
LEFT JOIN tagging ON calllist.org_id = tagging.org_id
LEFT JOIN contacts ON organization.id = contacts.org_id
GROUP BY contacts.org_id order by calllist.id ;
  ELSE
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_tagged_org AS
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( organization_tag.tag_name
SEPARATOR ', ' ) AS tags,tmp_tags.org_id AS tagged_org_id
FROM organization_tag
INNER JOIN tmp_tags ON organization_tag.id = tmp_tags.tag_id
GROUP BY tmp_tags.org_id;
SELECT calllist.id AS DT_RowId,tagging.tag_id, tmp_tagged_org.tags AS display_tag, organization.name, (
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( CONCAT( CONCAT( contacts.first_name, ' ', contacts.last_name ), ':', contacts.phone )
SEPARATOR '<br> ' )
FROM contacts
WHERE organization.id = org_id
) AS
unames,CONCAT(calllist.call_back_date,' ' , if(calllist.call_back_date < now(), '<label style='position:absolute'><i class='fa fa-warning' style='color:red'></i></label>', ' ')) as calldate,IF(tmp_tagged_org.tags IS NULL,'<input type='hidden' class='servicetags' style='width:150px'>',CONCAT('<input type='hidden' class='servicetags' value='',tmp_tagged_org.tags,'' style=' width:150px' >')) as tag_name
FROM calllist
INNER JOIN organization ON organization.id = calllist.org_id AND organization.user_id = userId
LEFT JOIN tmp_tagged_org ON tmp_tagged_org.tagged_org_id =  calllist.org_id
LEFT JOIN tagging ON calllist.org_id = tagging.org_id
LEFT JOIN contacts ON organization.id = contacts.org_id
GROUP BY contacts.org_id order by calllist.id;  
  END IF;
END $$
DELIMITER;
```

Comment: change `DECLARE i integer $$` to `DECLARE i integer;`

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE i integer' at line 2 @Vipin Jain. but i got the same error while using "declare i int;"   @ amdixon, @ Puya

Comment: maybe this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24349684/error-on-declare-variable-in-mysql-procedure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First few lines should be as per below-

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `sp_name`$$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_name`()
BEGIN
DECLARE i integer
```

Comment: Thanks. But when modifying as your code it shows the error "One or more errors have occurred while processing your request:" @Zafar Malik

Answer (score 0):

`$$` is the delimiter that will be used to close off the stored procedure definition, so it should *not* be immediately after your declaration (i.e., within the procedure itself). That declaration should still be using `;`.

Comment: yes. yes. but i got the same error while using "declare i int; @paxdiablo

Answer (score 0):

Change Declare Statement

```
 DECLARE i integer;
```